# How to synchronize fetch method in redux action

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am wondering how I can sync my fetch method. I want to prevent rendering data in a component before a response is returned.

Here is my redux action with my fetch method:

```
    export const FETCH_DATA_START = 'FETCH_DATA_START'
    export const FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS = 'FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS'
    export const FETCH_DATA_FAILED = 'FETCH_DATA_FAILED'

    export const getData = () => {
        return (dispatch) => {
            dispatch({
                type: FETCH_DATA_START
            })
            fetch(baseUrl, {
                    credentials: "include",
                    method: "GET",
                    headers: {
                        'Accept': 'application/json',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                })
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then((res) => {
                    dispatch({
                        type: FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS,
                        payload: res
                    })
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err)
                    dispatch({
                        type: FETCH_DATA_FAILED,
                        payload: 'error'
                    })
                })
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A common practice in this case is to set a flag like `isFetching` to true, and then display a loading spinner in your JSX based on the status of this flag.

Then when you received data, you hide this spinner and show the data.

Comment: I think fetch with await will be more suitable

Comment: Trying to make HTTP calls synchronous is usually a bad idea in terms of UX as it will freeze your UI. `async/await` feature is just a new syntax built on top of `Promises` to handle asynchronous code in a cleaner way. It is not here to make your calls synchronous.

Comment: so how make fetch method with await in my case ?

Comment: Please check sample from mdn on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await#Rewriting_promise_code_with_asyncawait